# Connect two different AWS Lambda layers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there any way to connect two different AWS Lambda layers?

Usually, we could invoke one lambda function by another lambda function. Is that possible in the lambda layer as well?

Comment: This question seems like it might be based on a misunderstanding of Lambda Layers and what they do.   Layers are passive collections of files... overlays that are extracted into the container where your function is running, before it starts.  What would "communication" look like, between zip files?

Answer (score 2):

Lambda layers are used for dependencies only and do not include application code that can be directly invoked. This provides the ability to create one set of dependencies and share them across lambda functions reducing the chance of issues with versioning of dependencies as well as reducing the over all amount of lambda code storage used by your account in the region. Per this link, AWS Provides 75GB of storage for lambda layers and function code per region.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

You can attach more than one layer to a lambda function. They will apply in a layer order until all layers have been added. This can be done using the web console. There is a "layers" button in the center of the console. Select it, then select a layer you have created and the version of the layer code.

To learn how to create a lambda layer for python, or see an example of lambda layers in use, please see these step by step video instructions: https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Create_Lambda_Layer_Python